# Firefox goes blank on refreshing an Intermediate page

Tags: c#, html, .net, firefox, model-view-controller

I'm working through a problem, where my Web application gets directed to a 3rd party application. There is an intermediate page, from where I can go back to my application or another 3rd party application. However, on refreshing this screen on Firefox, this screen goes blank with no html being loaded. The same thing works on Chrome but Firefox got the issue. On debugging locally this works well for both. Getting issue on deployed version only.

Note: This is a Dot Net angular application.

The link doesn't change on refreshing though.

1. While debugging, I figured out Request.UrlReferrer object is null, so I hardcoded it with the correct object data. Works well for firefox locally but not on deployed version.
2. Refreshed caches and cookies.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.